# Semantic UI- can't get popover to work on table rows

Tags: css, popover, semantic-ui

I'm having a heck of a time getting popovers to cooperate in Semantic UI. I have a basic table in a sidebar, and I need to display a popover whenever someone hovers over a table row. Seems basic enough but I can't for the life of me get it to work.

Typically in Semantic you embed the popover's HTML right next to the affected element as a sibling. Then you call

```
$(".user-popover").popup({
    position: 'right center'
});
```

For whatever reason, my popover won't appear. Can anyone help me out?

https://jsfiddle.net/edfdqzbw/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation:

> If its not possible to include the popup content as the next sibling,
>   you can also specify a custom selector to help link the popup contents
>   to its activator.

Hence:

```
$(function () {
    $(".user-popover").popup({
        hoverable: true,
        popup : $('.popup'),
        position: 'right center',
        lastResort: 'right center'
    });
});
```

DEmo: https://jsfiddle.net/edfdqzbw/3/ (see that next sibling is actually `<tr>`, that was problem)